# somehow one of my methods changes its field even when I duplicated itself

Tags: java

This is the class that contains method calculateTotalTipOnTable() calculateTotalTipOnTable method uses a method from the Customer class, and that method has no problem when I tested I think somehow calculateTotalTipOnTable manipulate the deque (when I test calculateTotalTipOnTable, it shrink the size of the TableDequeue)

```
package com.kristopher.restaurantmanager;

import sofia.graphics.RectangleShape;


public class TableDeque
    extends RectangleShape
    implements Deque<Customer>

{
    // ~ Instance/static variables ............................................
    private Node<Customer> head;
    private Node<Customer> tail;
    private int            size;
    private double         totalDue = 0;
    private double         totalTip = 0;
    private boolean        authorized;
    private TableDeque duplicate;


    /**
     * Constructor of the TableDeque class.
     */
    public TableDeque()
    {
        head = new Node<Customer>(null);
        tail = new Node<Customer>(null);
        head.join(tail);
        size = 0;
        this.setImage("table");

    }


    /**
     * Insert a new Customer at the rear (the tail) of the Tabledequeue.
     *
     * @param value
     *            the Customer to insert.
     */
    public void enqueueCustomerAtRear(Customer value)
    {
        Node<Customer> oldRear = tail.previous();
        tail.previous().split();
        oldRear.join((new Node<Customer>(value)).join(tail));
        size++;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Remove the Customer at the front (the head) of the deque.
     *
     * @return The Customer that was removed
     */
    public Customer dequeueCustomerAtFront()
    {
        Node<Customer> oldFrontNext = head.next().next();
        Node<Customer> oldFront = head.next();
        head.next().split();
        head.split();
        head.join(oldFrontNext);
        size--;
        return oldFront.data();
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Insert a new Customer at the front (the head) of the deque.
     *
     * @param value
     *            the Customer to insert.
     */
    public void enqueueCustomerAtFront(Customer value)
    {
        Node<Customer> oldFront = head.next();
        head.split();
        head.join((new Node<Customer>(value)).join(oldFront));
        size++;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Remove the Customer at the rear (the tail) of the deque.
     *
     * @return The Customer that was removed
     */
    public Customer dequeueCustomerAtRear()
    {
        Node<Customer> oldRearPrevious = tail.previous().previous();
        Node<Customer> oldRear = tail.previous();
        oldRearPrevious.split();
        oldRear.split();
        oldRearPrevious.join(tail);
        size--;
        return oldRear.data();

    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get the Customer at the front (the head) of the deque. Does not alter the
     * deque.
     *
     * @return the Customer at the front of the deque.
     */
    public Customer frontCustomer()
    {
        return head.next().data();
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get the Customer at the rear (the tail) of the deque. Does not alter the
     * deque.
     *
     * @return the Customer at the rear of the deque.
     */
    public Customer rearCustomer()
    {
        return tail.previous().data();
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get the number of items in this deque. Does not alter the deque.
     *
     * @return The number of items this deque contains.
     */
    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Empty the deque.
     */
    public void clear()
    {
        while (frontCustomer() != null)
        {
            dequeueCustomerAtRear();
        }
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this deque. A deque's string
     * representation is written as a comma-separated list of its contents (in
     * front-to-rear order) surrounded by square brackets, like this:
     *
     * <pre>
     * [koo, david, karl, tom]
     * </pre>
     * <p>
     * An empty deque is simply <code>[]</code>.
     * </p>
     *
     * @return Customer lists on a signle table.
     */
    public String customerList()
    {
        String s = "[";
        int count = 0;
        Node<Customer> c = head.next();
        while (c != tail)
        {
            if (count < size() - 1)
            {
                s = s + c.data().getName() + ", ";
                c = c.next();
            }
            else
            {
                s = s + c.data().getName() + "]";
                c = c.next();
            }
            count++;
        }
        return s;
    }


    // -----------------------------------------------------
    // Table money process methods
    // -----------------------------------------------------

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * tableDue calculate the total due amount of the table. This method use
     * duplicated information of the table not to hurt any stored value beside
     * the double value totalDue
     *
     * @return total due on the table.
     */
    public double tableDue()
    {
        duplicate = this.duplicate();
        while (duplicate.size() != 0)
        {
            totalDue += duplicate.dequeueCustomerAtFront().getDueAmount();
        }
        duplicate = null;
        return totalDue;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    // somehow this method change the table itself(not duplicated table.)
    // has to be fixed
    /**
     * calculateTotalTipOnTable method calculate the total tip amount that
     * customers gives you. This method must be called only when all of the
     * customer has done payingProcess
     *
     * @return total tip amount on table
     */
    public double calculateTotalTipOnTable()
    {
        duplicate = this.duplicate();
        while (duplicate.size() != 0)
        {
            totalTip += duplicate.frontCustomer().totalTipAmount();
            duplicate.dequeueCustomerAtFront();
        }
        duplicate = null;
        return totalTip;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * This method will determine if it is okey to remove table based on the
     * bollean value stored in this class, and customer class. This method count
     * the number of customers that is already authorized(means they paid). If
     * counts equal to the size of the deque, this table is authorized and ready
     * to dismiss.
     *
     * @return name of the customer who didn't fully pay yet.
     */
    public String payingProcess()
    {
        duplicate = this.duplicate();
        int count = 0;
        String str = "";
        if (duplicate.size() != 0)
        {
            while (duplicate.size() != 0)
            {
                if (duplicate.frontCustomer().isPaid())
                {
                    count++;
                    this.dequeueCustomerAtFront();
                    duplicate.dequeueCustomerAtFront();
                }
                else
                {
                    str += duplicate.frontCustomer().getName();
                    duplicate.dequeueCustomerAtFront();
                }
            }
            authorized = (count == this.size());
            duplicate = null;
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            duplicate = null;
            authorized = true;
            return "table is empty";
        }
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * return boolean if this table is ready to be dismissed
     *
     * @return boolean authorized
     */
    public boolean isPaid()
    {
        return authorized;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * this is the helper method to produce duplicate Table.
     * @return duplicated table.
     */
    public TableDeque duplicate()
    {
        TableDeque duplicate1 = new TableDeque();
        duplicate1 = this;
        return duplicate1;
    }

**payingProcess method of Customer Class.**
public double payingProcess(double d, double t)
    {
        actualTip = t;
        totalTip += t;
        double x = d - this.getDueAmount();
        if (d >= 0.0)
        {
            authorized = (x >= 0.0);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("negative value of payment");
        }

        if (authorized)
        {
            totalPayDue = 0;
            paidAmount = paidAmount + d;
            return x;
        }
        else
        {
            totalPayDue -= d;
            paidAmount = paidAmount + d;
            return Math.abs(x);
        }
    }
```

TestCase file 
Errors portion >>//////assertEquals(table.calculateTotalTipOnTable(), 15.0);//////////////// assertEquals(customer1.totalTipAmount(), 15.0);////

```
package com.kristopher.restaurantmanager;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TableDequeTests
    extends TestCase
{
    private TableDeque table;
    private Customer   customer1;
    private Customer   customer2;
    private Customer   customer3;
    private Customer   customer4;
    private Food       food1;
    private Food       food2;
    private Food       food3;


    public void setUp()
    {
        table = new TableDeque();
        customer1 = new Customer("Kristopher");// customer who don't order
        customer2 = new Customer("Mike");// customer who order one food
        customer3 = new Customer("Yilong");// customer who order two foods
        customer4 = new Customer("Barnette");// customer who order three foods
        food1 = new Food("Kimchi", 10.00);
        food2 = new Food("Bulgogi", 20.00);
        food3 = new Food("GamzaTang", 30.00);
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        customer2.setOrderedFood(food1);// Mike

        customer3.setOrderedFood(food1);// Yilong
        customer3.setOrderedFood(food2);

        customer4.setOrderedFood(food1);// Barnette
        customer4.setOrderedFood(food2);
        customer4.setOrderedFood(food3);
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Test if tableDue method correctly caclulate the total due of the table.
     */
    public void testTableDue()
    {
        table.enqueueCustomerAtFront(customer3);
        assertEquals(table.tableDue(), 30.0, 0.0);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * This method must calculate the total tip on the table.
     */
    public void testCalculateTotalTipOnTable()
    {
        table.enqueueCustomerAtFront(customer1);
        table.enqueueCustomerAtFront(customer2);
        customer1.payingProcess(0.0, 15.0);
        customer2.payingProcess(0.0, 35.0);
        assertEquals(50.0, table.calculateTotalTipOnTable());
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Testing if enqueueCustomerAtRear correctly enque at rear of the table
     * deque.
     */
    public void testTableForSingleCustomer()
    {
        table.enqueueCustomerAtFront(customer1);
        assertEquals(table.size(), 1);
        assertEquals(table.frontCustomer().getName(), "Kristopher");

        Exception thrown = null;
        try
        {
            table.rearCustomer().getOrderFood();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            thrown = e;
        }
        assertTrue(thrown instanceof IllegalStateException);
        assertEquals(
            thrown.getMessage(),
            "This customer did not order any foods yet");

        assertEquals(table.customerList(), "[Kristopher]");
        assertEquals(table.tableDue(), 0.0, 0.0);
        customer1.payingProcess(0.0, 15.0);
        //////assertEquals(table.calculateTotalTipOnTable(), 15.0);////////////
       //// assertEquals(customer1.totalTipAmount(), 15.0);////
        assertEquals(table.payingProcess(), "table is empty");
        assertTrue(table.isPaid());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating a duplicate here :

```
public TableDeque duplicate()
{
    TableDeque duplicate1 = new TableDeque();
    duplicate1 = this;
    return duplicate1;
}
```

You are returning a refernce to the original instance.

Instead of the `duplicate` method, you can use a copy constructor:

```
public TableDeque (TableDeque copy)
{
    // copy properties from the source TableDeque to the new instance
}
```

Then, instead of calling

```
duplicate = this.duplicate();
```

You'll call

```
duplicate = new TableDeque(this);
```

Comment: I am trying to do what you said, but I don't understand "copy properties from the source TableDeque to the new instance" means without using "=". how do I copy all of the data that original constructor has??

Comment: @정구현 You can initialize the new instance with the same code as the original constructor by calling this() in the first line of the new constructor. but then you must copy all the Nodes of the original instance to the new instance.

Comment: I really appreciate your replies, and I tried... but I still don't know how to duplicate Deque..... ;(............................

Comment: public TableDeque(TableDeque copy)
    {
        this();
        
    } stucked after this();